# How to load a postcss plugin after css is scoped by vue's style-post-loader

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, postcss, vue-loader, postcss-loader

I am writing a `postcss` plugin intended to be used in a `vue.js` project. This plugin needs to run *after* `vue-loader` has processed the `css` and added any scoped id's to the selectors. Is there a way with `vue.config.js`, or some other way, to specify the order of `postcss` plugins?

Currently I have my plugin being included in `postcss.config.js`. I see that `add-id` for scoped styles is itself a `postcss` plugin defined [here](https://github.com/vuejs/component-compiler-utils/blob/master/lib/stylePlugins/scoped.ts#L6), but I'm not sure how it is actually used.

My `postcss` config and plugin files:

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('./postcss-mycustomplugin')()
    ]
};
```

```
// postcss-mycustomplugin.js
var postcss = require('postcss');

module.exports = postcss.plugin('mycustomplugin', function mycustomplugin(options) {
    return function (css) {
        // `css` still has not been processed by vue's postcss plugin
    }
});
```

To reiterate, I'd like my plugin to run on the `css` after scoped id's have been added.